# In C#, how does one convert from a windows system time to EDT, provided the windows system doesn't observe DST?

Tags: c#, windows, datetime, timezone

We have a windows system that is set to **not** adjust it's time for DST. Of course, we need to display the proper time to users in wall-clock time, in our case EDT.

In our older (much, much older) systems we had to define dates when the clock would go forward or back an hour and convert times based on weather we were in DST or not.

How would this work in a windows system with c#?

Does windows know when it's in DST even though it's set up not to adjust for it?

I suspect that the conversion only works if your system is set to adjust for DST. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the current time in the US Eastern time zone, accounting for both EST and EDT:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tz);
```

It does not matter if the machine it is running on has DST enabled or not, or if it is in a different time zone entirely.  A named time zone will use the full rules for that time zone.

With regard to a system set up to disable automatic daylight saving time adjustments, .NET will take that into consideration when converting to or from the *local* time zone only.  In other words, when using `TimeZoneInfo.Local`, or `DateTime.ToLocalTime`, or `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` (coming *from* local time), etc.

Additionally, it is generally not recommended for users of Windows systems to disable the automatic DST feature.  The option to disable it is primarily a legacy configuration.  Instead, users should simply pick the correct time zone for the location they are in.